# S3 policy - public write but only authenticated read

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What I am trying to do is to let (anonymous) users share files to a specified bucket. However, they should not be possible to READ the files, which are already there (and for all I care not even the ones they submitted themselves). The only account which should be able to list/get objects from the bucket should be the bucket owner.

Here is what I got so far:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "PutOnlyPolicy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow_PublicPut",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myputbucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Deny_Read",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myputbucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow_BucketOwnerRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::myAWSAccountID:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myputbucket/*"
    }
]
}
```

The above Policy enables me to write files to the bucket (f.e. via the android app S3anywhere), but I can't GET the objects, not even with my authenticated account.

Do you have any hints on how I could accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Allowing anonymous access to your bucket is a tremendous mistake.  Just don't.  But if you do anyway, it's critical that you force the ACL to be `bucket-owner-full-control` via policy -- otherwise you'll end up with objects that **you** cannot download, you can only delete.  There is **no** valid use case for anonymous uploads.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous users are not able to read a bucket content by default. So you should have only these lines in your policy:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "PutOnlyPolicy",
   "Statement": [
   {
      "Sid": "Allow_PublicPut",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myputbucket/*"
   }    
]
}
```

Comment: As said to another answer: this was my first attempt; I once again copy+pasted your policy. Curiously if I upload a file to the bucket, as said f.e. via the app S3anywhere, I can still publicly GET the file. That's why I decided to DENY the GET explicitly, which works, but in that case it works too good and it DENY-s even me as the bucketowner. :/

Comment: @konrad_pe: Iurii's answer should work for you (as long as your bucket has no other allow-public-read rule defined somewhere else, like in the bucket `Permissions` pane in the management console).

Comment: The `Permissions` pane has 2 entries for this bucket: Grantee "ME" (all permissions) as well as "Any Authenticated AWS User" (LIST). Which doesn't explain why I am able to access the objects from public, right? As said, the objects themselves have no permissions set to them.

Answer (score 0):

The deny statement in your policy takes precedence over everything else. The default is to deny everything that isn't specifically allowed, so you should be able to just remove the deny statement and all will work the way you want.

Comment: This was my first attempt, curiously if I upload a file to the bucket, as said f.e. via the app S3anywhere, I can still publicly GET the file. The uploaded file has no permissions attached at all, so I wouldve guessed that it inherits the permissions from the bucket.

Comment: Have you played with the AWS IAM policy simulator? What results do you get from that?

Answer (score 0):

Policy looks good, I guess that problem into **Principal**, you can look how it use into documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html. Probably you should use **AccountNumber-WithoutHyphens**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; I've also been there already. F.e. I tried it with `"Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"64-digit-alphanumeric-value"}` (of course where the 64-digit value is my canonical user id from https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=eu-central-1#/security_credential ). Results in no GET possible at all for this bucket.